# Postman test collection running well, all tests passed in Postman but all tests fails using Newman i comman line

Tags: postman, postman-newman

My postman tests runs well and passes when i run the collection in postman. I've exported and saved my Postman collection.json into a folder, but when running the json file using Newman, all tests fails. some of the errors are:-

- getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND {{baseurl}} at request
- expected { Object (id, _details, ...) } to have property 'code' at assertion:0 in test-script
- Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at test-script

Comment: Did you also export your environment?

Comment: @ChristianBaumann No sure i did that. It's my first time to do this.

Comment: Especially the `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND {{baseurl}}` appears like an evnironment variable is missing/ not set.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann, do i export and save the environment as a json format in the same folder as the collections?

Comment: Can be same or different folder, you pass in the path via the `-e, --environment [file|URL]` switch, see https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/#options

Answer (score 0):

Export your environment file as json. Pass it in the newman command line as "-e" parameter.

```
$ newman run yourcollectionfile.json -e yourenvironmentfile.json
```

When running postman, you also have to specify the environment file you are using. Documentation for this is found here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a local variable in your exported collection . i was facing the simliar issue made all variables as local and my test passed.